# How to create Responsive webpage?

Tags: html, css

What are the best ways to create responsive webpage? Is Skeleton Framework compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish?  As it stands, this question is far too broad/vague to be objectively answerable.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad and also not constructive: `As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.`. So bad I'm out of close votes. For the second part of your question you should [find the answer on Skeleton's homepage](http://www.getskeleton.com/#support).

Comment: Responsive as in dynamic? Use JavaScript, AJAX, JQUERY, etc....

Comment: Look into CSS Media Queries...

Comment: There are enough resources out there about the topic. There's no need to regurgitate any of it here. Please focus on *specific questions* if you have any.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with reponsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this link: http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/

There you can find HOW to do it and some links to tutorials AND frameworks.
And for all others who don't know what responsive websites are, can use this link, too :D

Comment: Thanks! Have you used any of the framework? I tried using Skeleton framework but its not working in IE. But they say it supports IE.

Comment: No, sorry. Never used any of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources out there to understand what [Responsive web design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) is. It is vital that you understand what suits you and your requirement. So it is not easy to give a  generic answer to a question such as yours. However, basic principles are explained in the above article. Once you understand the basics clearly, you can look into frameworks such as [LESS](http://lessframework.com/) or [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com)  for more boilerplate type stuff.